# splitting an array of arrays, [0] into one, [1] into another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a basic array of arrays `[[1,2],[2,4],[3,6]]`

I want to split that into two arrays, so that...

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,4,6]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply use [Array#transpose](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/transpose) as below,

```
arr = [[1,2],[2,4],[3,6]]
# => [[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6]] 

a, b = arr.transpose
# => [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6]] 
a
# => [1, 2, 3] 
b
# => [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: `transpose` is best +1

Comment: Anything using of `transpose` really does rack up the upvotes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
c = [[1,2],[2,4],[3,6]]
```

You can use map and insert into two different arrays

```
a = c.map{|x,y| x}
# => [1, 2, 3]

b = c.map{|x,y| y}
 #=> [2, 4, 6]
```

**Edit** As @DaveMongoose comment you can also write this

```
a = c.map(&:first)
b = c.map(&:last)
```

Comment: These could also be written `a = c.map(&:first)` and `b = c.map(&:last)`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with a function like `each`, and to take advantage of Ruby's automatic array splitting:

```
ary = [[1,2],[2,4],[3,6]]
a = []
b = []

ary.each{|first,second| a << first; b << second}
# The entry [1,2] is automatically split into first = 1 and second = 2
```

If you want, you can also write it in a single method call using `each_with_object`

```
a,b = ary.each_with_object([[],[]]) do |(first, second), result|
  result[0] << first
  result[1] << second
}
```

A third option would be to use `Array.zip`:

```
a,b = ary[0].zip(*ary[1..-1])
```

`zip` combines arrays by pairing up the entries with the same indices (as you want to do here). The `*` here is the splat operator, which unwraps the array of arrays into a series of arguments.

Comment: The best way here is `transpose`. `each` should be used only when there's no more specific method that can do the job.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So it is! I completely forgot about `transpose`

Comment: Good to know how to do this without transpose.